# Ubuntu One indicator applet not showing in XFCE

Tags: xubuntu, applet

I have recently installed the Xubuntu desktop alongside Ubuntu on my netbook, as it's lighter. I also have the Ubuntu One indicator applet, which shows up fine in the Ubuntu desktop but is replaced by something rather less appealing in Xubuntu.

Here's the screen shot - look to the right of the network indicator:

[image: Here's the screen shot - look to the right of the network indicator:]

Can I get the regular applet to show on the Xubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the Ubuntu One notification icon in Xubuntu 12.10

Try this:

```
Settings Manager --> Appearance --> Icons --> Ubuntu-Mono-Light
```

It should get you a little Ubuntu-One-cloud-like-thingy...

Comment: There, you can add your image now ;)